# Where I can ask about Facebook?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to ask a question about Facebook. Where I should post my question on Stack Exchange?

> Someone created a fake Facebook account using my name and my picture; is there a way to discover the phone number or email that was used to create the fake account? How I can discover who did that, and what is the best way to stop it?

If Stack Exchange doesn't have a site to ask about Facebook, I suggest adding a website to allow us to post questions about it.

Comment: That has nothing to do with StackExchange.  Just talk to Facebook directly.

Comment: Also question updated

Comment: Maybe [webapps.se] might be appropriate, but I don't have any account there so I'm not sure, so I recommend reading their help center first. Also, in your specific case, you might want to contact Facebook directly.

Comment: You can't request a website here: that happens on area 51. But I get the feeling a site about Facebook will not get too much support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General questions about using Facebook (excepting the use of the smartphone app) are on-topic at [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com). (Please see the [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) tag.)

However, your example question is a support question and should be directed to Facebook. [How do I report an account for impersonation?](https://www.facebook.com/help/174210519303259)

Comment: While the question would be on topic the answer is to contact Facebook since they are the only entity that can remove the fake account